# Run a macro on a selection of cells

Tags: vba, excel, cells

I wrote the following macro to help me on a VLOOKUP repetitive action. 
It works, but I can't manage to run it on several cells at the same time.

I guess there's a code to write at the beginning of the macro.

Help much appreciated ;-)

```
    Sub Croisement_ZANOX_BO()
'
' Croisement_ZANOX_BO Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC3,BO!C[-18]:C[-11],1,FALSE)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC3,BO!C[-19]:C[-12],2,FALSE)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC3,BO!C[-20]:C[-13],3,FALSE)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC3,BO!C[-21]:C[-14],4,FALSE)"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC3,BO!C[-22]:C[-15],5,FALSE)"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC3,BO!C[-23]:C[-16],6,FALSE)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC3,BO!C[-24]:C[-17],7,FALSE)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC3,BO!C[-25]:C[-18],8,FALSE)"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "# ##0,00 €"
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell` literally means **active cell**. What are you trying to do and what does not work?

Comment: @mehow but he's changing cell using `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select`. It's not a good code, but.....

Comment: Insead of write the vlookup every time you could (i) record a macro (ii) write the code in the cell (iii) copy and paste or autofill.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid the use of `.Select/ActiveCell` etc as @Makah suggested. 
[INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

If the formula that you want to use is say `=VLOOKUP($C1,BO!D:XFA,N,FALSE)` where `n` is the column number in the formula (based on your above code) and you want to put that from say `D1` then use a simple loop like this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long, col As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    col = 4 '<~~ For COl D

    With ws
        For n = 1 To 8
            .Cells(1, col).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($C1,BO!D:XFA," & n & ",FALSE)"
            col = col + 1
        Next n
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Siddhart, 
Thanks a lot for your help. 

I'm getting an error 91 while using this : 
In fact I have 2 sheets in the same workbook, they have one column in common and I'm trying to automatically merge the data.

Thanks a lot!

`code`Sub Croisement_ZANOX_BO_2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long, col As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = test.Sheets("Zanox")

    col = 4 '<~~ For COl D

    With ws
        For n = 1 To 8
             .Cells(1, col).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($C1,BO!D:XFA," & n & ",FALSE)"
            col = col + 1
        Next n
    End With
End Sub